# TypeError: { } is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write (append) string of python dict to Google Sheets

below is my code

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
SPREADSHEET_ID = 'XXX'
RANGE_NAME = 'Sheet1!A2:F2'
now = time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')


def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


    request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId= SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                                 range= RANGE_NAME,
                                                 valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
                                                 insertDataOption='INSERT_ROWS',
                                                 body= {now, data2['pagespeed_score'], data2['yslow_score'], Loadedtime, pagesize, data2['page_elements'],})
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I am getting an error:

```
"TypeError: {2.1982345581054688, '11-09-2018 13:08', 8.836, 109, 52, 55} is not JSON serializable"
```

What I think is the values should be in json format but my values are in python dictionary.

Comment: Your values is not a dict, it's a set.

Comment: It's not dictionary, it's a set. Use `key=value` to make a dictionary.

Comment: Per the API Spec for `values#append`, the `body` parameter must be a `ValueRange`: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#request-body  Review the API docs and possibly also the Python Client Library docs: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.values.html#append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the code as below, changed the set of values to dict

```
values = [now, pagespeed, yslow, Loadedtime, pagesize, element]
body = {'values': [values]} 


result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME,
    valueInputOption= 'USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 body= {now, data2['pagespeed_score'], data2['yslow_score'], Loadedtime, pagesize, data2['page_elements'],}
```

you're passing a `set`, which doesn't have any equivalent in JSON. You'll have to check the google sheet API documentation for the expected type (probably a `dict` actually).